# Function createtopology(unknown, integer, integer) does not exist. Not able run PostGIS function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to run this function

```
SELECT public.CreateTopology('topo1',4326,0);
```

which gives me

```
ERROR:  function public.createtopology(unknown, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select public.CreateTopology('topo1',4326,0);
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

I can use other PostGIS function without trouble. This one however does not work. Note, there are many schems in my database. Why is that?

Comment: [According to the manual](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/CreateTopology.html) the third parameter needs to be a double, try: `CreateTopology('topo1',4326,0::double precision)`

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter is optional, but if present is data type `double precision`, if omitted defaults to 0. (see [Postgis documentation CreateTopology](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/CreateTopology.html). So try

```
SELECT public.CreateTopology('topo1',4326,0::double precision);
          OR 
SELECT public.CreateTopology('topo1',4326,0.0); 
          OR
SELECT public.CreateTopology('topo1',4326);
```

UPDATE: As posted `'topo1'` is a string literal. But it needs to be `Topology`. You need to correct the data type.

Comment: thats not working... same error

Comment: Updated answer and corrected link.  Your data type is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. `topo1` needs to be `varchar topology_schema_name`... Basically a `string`. How comes this is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my misreading.